# If $f$ is injective, then $f(X\backslash A) = f(X) \backslash f(A)$

Tags: functions, proof-writing

**Given $f:X \to Y$ injective, $A \subseteq X$, then $f(X\backslash A) =
 f(X) \backslash f(A)$**

I have spent a long time looking at this problem but I have not found a good way to approach this.

Here is my work:

Let $f$ be injective, then $\forall a,b \in X, a \neq b \implies f(a) \neq f(b)$,

Can attempt to generalize this (?), given $A, B \subseteq X, A \cap B = \varnothing \implies f(A) \cap f(B) = \varnothing$

Then let $B = X\backslash A$, $A \cap (X\backslash A) = \varnothing$, then $f(A) \cap f(X \backslash A) = \varnothing$

Attempted to massage the above by unioning with $f(X)$ and then taking complement of $f(A)$, does not seem to work.

Can someone please [image]

Comment: Perhaps it might help you to think of it from another perspective.  Try proving $f(X\setminus A)\subseteq f(X)\setminus f(A)$ and vice versa.  Do so by taking elements of each side.  Let $y\in f(X\setminus A)$.  Then there is some $x\in X\setminus A$ such that $f(x)=y$.  Then $x\in X$ and $x\not\in A$.  Since $f$ is injective...  For the reverse inclusion, let $y\in f(X)\setminus f(A)$.  Then $y\in f(X)$ and $y\not\in f(A)$.  Then there exists some $x\in X$ such that $f(x)=y$.  Further there exist no $a\in A$ such that $f(a)=y$.  Thus...

Comment: Might also be useful to place your definition of injective in contraposition:  "$f(a) = f(b) \implies a = b$".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first we show if $B\subseteq\,Y$ and $C\subseteq\,Y$ then  $f^{-1}(B-C)=f^{-1}(B)-f^{-1}(C)$:

$$x\in f^{-1}(B-C)\Leftrightarrow f(x)\in\,B-C\Leftrightarrow f(x)\in\,B \,\wedge\, f(x)\notin\,C\Leftrightarrow\,x\in\,f^{-1}(B)\wedge\,x\notin\,f^{-1}(C)$$
$$x\in f^{-1}(B-C)\Leftrightarrow\,x\in\,f^{-1}(B)-\,f^{-1}(C)$$

Now we can prove this theorem: $f$ is injective so

$$f^{-1}(f(X)-f(A))=f^{-1}(f(X))-f^{-1}(f(A))=X-A $$
then
 $$f(X)-f(A)=f(X-A)$$